# How can I hear when the user presses the submit button on a SearchView but the user has not entered any text

Tags: android, searchview

Hello I am trying to know when the user hits the search/submit button on a searchView but they have not entered any text. I am aware I can use setOnQueryTextListener but this will only get called if the user enters some text. If you have any ideas please let me know. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

verify the length of the text entered like this:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String key) {
     if(key.length()>2){//if the text to search more then 2 caracter
     //user hit the search button, do your search
    }
     return false;}

 @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
  // user is typing ...
   return false;
    }
            });
```

Comment: thank you for your response, is there any way I can get when the user clicks the submit button but there is no text entered?

Comment: when the submit button clicked and the text in empty he doesn't call onQueryTextSubmit, take a look at this link [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html] you'll found all the methods available for searchView